# Wait-free ring buffer

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, embedded

I have a scenario where I could have multiple producers but single consumer of a ring-buffer. here is the source code:

```
typedef struct ring_buffer_t {
    uint8_t *data;
    uint32_t element_size;
    uint32_t element_count;
    uint32_t head;
    uint32_t tail;
    uint32_t mask;
} ring_buffer;

uint32_t ring_buffer_put(ring_buffer *buf, void *data_element) {
    int i;
    uint32_t status = 0;
    uint8_t *buf_pointer;
    uint8_t *element = (uint8_t *) data_element;

    if (buf && data_element) {

        buf_pointer = &buf->data[(buf->head & buf->mask) * buf->element_size];
        for (i = 0; i < buf->element_size; ++i) {
            buf_pointer[i] = element[i];
        }

        status = 1;
        __sync_fetch_and_add(&buf->head, 1);

    }

    return status;
}

uint32_t ring_buffer_size(ring_buffer *buf) {

    return buf->head - buf->tail;
}

uint32_t ring_buffer_empty(ring_buffer *buf) {

    return (ring_buffer_size(buf) == 0);
}

void *ring_buffer_get(ring_buffer *buf) {
    void *element;
    //preserve the invariant that tail is always <= head
    if (ring_buffer_empty(buf)) {
        return 0;
    }

    element = &buf->data[(buf->tail & buf->mask) * buf->element_size];
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&buf->tail, 1);
    return element;
}
```

The problem statements allows me to overwrite older entries e.g. that's why I'm using the and and there is no checking for whether the buffer is full when putting - I just overwrite the oldest entry. However, I'm having hard time reasoning whether this is thread safe. As stated earlier - it is important that this is wait-free (respectively lock-free by definition) since producers cannot afford to block. The size will always be a power of 2 so that's why the & during indexing works.

Any input will be appreciated?

Comment: I do not see how it can be thread-safe, __sync_fetch_and_add is indeed atomic, but what prevents a race condition?  I do not see it.

Comment: The only wait-free ring buffer implementation is one that calls exit(1) when the buffer overflows.

Comment: Technically, the buffer can never get full because it is perfectly OK to overwrite old entries.

Answer (score 0):

No, your implementation is not thread safe.

If two threads `put` elements simultaneously they can end up writing in the same position, or even half a record in one position and the other half in the next position.

Comment: It is indeed thread unsafe for the multi producer, single consumer case. Though it will work for single consumer, single producer. In order to make it thread-safe for SCMP I'd have to resort to something similar to what disruptor is doing http://blog.codeaholics.org/2011/the-disruptor-lock-free-publishing/